# Mixing texture paint and exported UV png changes color of png...?

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, texture-painting, vector-mapping

I'm trying to mix a basic texture I made in the texture paint mode, and a transparent png I made from the 'export UV layout' option. They technically both appear, but the transparent one has changed from a blue-black (which I want) to a brown (which I don't want...) and I'm not sure why. I attempted to just plug in a hue/saturation node to quickly alter the color but it alters the color of the supposedly-transparent png background. Because of this, I had to plug in an invert node which ostensibly fixed the problem and made it transparent again, but the png is still brown. Here are some pictures...
[image]
[image]

The symbols are meant to be tattoos, and they're mixed with the plain beige texture paint. Is the beige what's changing the color of the tattoos? Without the invert node, it looks like this...

[image]

Thanks in advance!! I'm sure it's just something small and random I've missed. I'm still pretty much a noob.

Comment: On the Color Mix Node, invert the order there to put the Alpha image on the bottom and the Body image into the top socket - that way the alpha image appears on top. Blender uses the opposite of what you think the order would be coming from an Image Editor in stacks of layers, this is more like a Text Editor where next line below is last added.

Comment: Thanks!! That got rid of the inversion problem. It's still brown though...? Is that an effect of the texture paint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the answer to "why is it brown" is that the subsurface scattering color was pink and I had the slider turned up really high. -sigh- It's always something little like that isn't it

EDIT: here is a screenshot of what it looked like after I altered the subsurface color
[image]

Comment: Maybe as an improvement on this, share a picture of before and after on the Subsurface color mixing so the answer can be seen as well.

Comment: Good suggestion; I edited my answer to include a photo